# Getting input from multiple keyboards in XNA

Tags: c#, input, xna

I was looking at documentation for keyboard input in xna and I noticed something interesting: it accepts a `PlayerIndex` argument, like xbox controllers.

My question is: is it therefore possible to get input from multiple keyboards at the same time using `PlayerIndex.One`, `Two`, `Three`, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975640.aspx) says:

> Returns the current Chatpad state for the specified player.
>
> Each player can have his or her own Chatpad, which is queried as a
> keyboard. To query an attached USB keyboard instead, use the GetState
> method that does not require a player index.
>
> This method works on Xbox 360 platforms only.

Comment: That's fine by me, I was just interested

Comment: I see, I just wanted to give you an explanation instead of writing only "no".

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can, but you'll have to do some legwork ...
have a look [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/32222/supporting-multiple-input-devices), and [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/285732-how-to-support-multiple-input-devices/) (the second have a link to another example if you wish to go on)